# How to find DynamoDB all table names that match a pattern?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

**I need to find all DynamoDB existing table names that start with a given string.**

What is the best/recommended way to do this?

I need to do this, for example to find all tables, whose name starts with `"__Test__"` and then delete all these tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do it programmatically, you would have to do it in these steps.

1. Call the [`ListTables`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_ListTables.html) API
2. Go through all of the [**TableNames**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_ListTables.html#DDB-ListTables-response-TableNames) in the response
3. Call [`DeleteTable`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteTable.html) on any table that has a name matching the `"__Test__"` pattern
4. If the [**LastEvaluatedTableName**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_ListTables.html#DDB-ListTables-response-LastEvaluatedTableName) is present in the response, repeat steps 1-3 setting the [**ExclusiveStartTableName**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_ListTables.html#DDB-ListTables-request-ExclusiveStartTableName) for pagination

There is also some requirements for calling `DeleteTable` regarding the table state. From the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteTable.html):

> The *DeleteTable* operation deletes a table and all of its items. After
>   a *DeleteTable* request, the specified table is in the `DELETING` state
>   until DynamoDB completes the deletion. If the table is in the `ACTIVE`
>   state, you can delete it. If a table is in CREATING or `UPDATING`
>   states, then DynamoDB returns a *ResourceInUseException*. If the
>   specified table does not exist, DynamoDB returns a
>   *ResourceNotFoundException*. If table is already in the `DELETING` state,
>   no error is returned.

If you only need to do this to a few tables and not recurring, you can go to the [AWS DynamoDB console](https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/console/home?region=us-west-2#) and (after selecting the right region) delete the table directly in the UI.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, +1. On a related topic, do you know any way to have the equivalent of "several databases", such as Dev database, Test database and Prod database, and have same-named tables in each of these databases? It would be very bad, if DynamoDB doesn't provide any such possibility.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev the old way (and way I am accustomed to) to do this is to create separate AWS accounts and use [consolidated billing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/consolidated-billing.html). I think the newer way to do this is to use [resource groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsconsolehelpdocs/latest/gsg/what-are-resource-groups.html), [IAM users](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/IAM_Introduction.html), and then naming conventions like table suffixes/prefixes.